# $\int_{\gamma}\left(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z-1}\right)dz=0$ on $\mathbb C\setminus[0,1]$

Tags: complex-analysis

> $\int_{\gamma}\left(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z-1}\right)dz=0$ on $U:=\mathbb C\setminus[0,1]$ for a closed path with image in $U$

For any analytic function $f$ and a closed path $\gamma$:   $\int_{\gamma}f(w)dw=0$, and I know that $\frac1z$ and $\frac{1}{z-1}$ are analytic, so is their difference ?

Comment: 1) If $0 \in \text{Interior}(\gamma)$ then $1 \in \text{Interior}(\gamma)$ since $\gamma$ can't cross $[0,1]$. 2) If  $a \in \text{Interior}(\gamma)$ then by Cauchy's theorem $\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z-a} =2\pi i$.

Answer (score 1):

Their difference is also anaytic, of course. Perhaps it's easier to see it as follows

$$\frac1z-\frac1{z-1}=-\frac1{z(z-1)}$$

and the above is anaytic on $\;\Bbb C\setminus\{0,1\}\;$, thus its integral is zero on any closed path *not containing* $\;0,1\;$ . What if it contains both points? Can you take it from here?

Comment: @Paul, check the edition done before your comment. Thanks

Comment: yes, I deleted.  You also need to show that such a path can only contain 0 or 2 points; it can't just contain one.

Comment: @Timbuc but in the question it is the interval $[0,1]$

Comment: @Paul True, and that's why I ask what I do at the end of my answer: a closed path as the one the OP wants can *only* contain both singular points, not only one.

Comment: @OBDA Yes, sure....so? I don't understand your question.

Answer (score -1):

If $f$ is holomorphic in a simply connected domain $U,$ then $\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0$ for every closed contour $\gamma$ in $U.$ In this problem, $U =\mathbb {C}\setminus [0,1]$ is simply connected, and $f(z) = 1/z-1/(z-1)$ is holomorphic in $U.$